# xml to linq query where letter starts with a in windows phone

Tags: c#, sql, xml, linq, windows-phone-8

i am trying to fetch data where all words starting with A and displaying it listbox using xml to LINQ, but the Startwith property i am not able acheve here is the code i am trying to fetch

```
XDocument loadedCustomData = XDocument.Load("accounts.xml");
            var filteredData =
               from c in loadedCustomData.Descendants("record")

               where  (string)c.Element("main") == "Above the Line"
                // i want here something like
                //where (string)c.element("main").startwith ==a
                //so how to ACHIEVE THIS????
               select new words()
               {

                   PON = "Post Office: " + (string)c.Element("main"),
                   PIN = "Pincode (Postal Code): " + (string)c.Element("def"),

               };
            listBox1.ItemsSource = filteredData;
```

here is the XML format

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <data-set xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<record>
      <main>Above the Line</main>
        <def>Above the line items are those revenue and expense items that directly affect          
</record>
```

SO HOW TO ACHIEVE THE QUERY TO START WITH LETTER A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
    XDocument loadedCustomData = XDocument.Load("accounts.xml");
    var filteredData =
       from c in loadedCustomData.Descendants("record")
       where ((string)c.Element("main")).StartsWith("A")
       select new words()
       {

           PON = "Post Office: " + (string)c.Element("main"),
           PIN = "Pincode (Postal Code): " + (string)c.Element("def"),

       };
    listBox1.ItemsSource = filteredData;
```